# N-Tier architecture with DAL, Repo, Service, API layers: what type of objects should each layer deal in/out + where should validation/mapping occur?

Tags: c#, web-services, validation, castle-windsor, n-tier-architecture

I think my application should have at least the following layers:

- DAL (no common interface; get the data from a database, get the data from another web service, get the data from a file)
- Repository (CRUD interface for each important/root aggregate; implementations vary by source)
- Service (consume repository interface; implementations vary by business logic)
- Web API (wrap services; install container; implementations vary by runtime parameters/config)

I know that my Web API should be returning DTO, which I interpret as C# objects with nothing but auto-implemented public properties.

In theory, sometimes I will need to do `BigComplicatedServiceCommand` where there will be multiple repositories involved in a single unit of work, but other times my Web API might as well call the repository directly because it is just doing CRUD.

I am interested in understanding *where* mapping from (input into web service via web api model binding) DTO to whatever the Service requires should take place - and also, where validation should take place.

Roughly speaking, I have this in my mind:

IN API

1. Receive request and map to route
2. Use model binder to bind to DTO by convention
3. Instantiate particular controller using IoC container
4. Run particular controller action
5. In controller action, wrap call to service layer

Now, after step 5 is problematic. Do I send the DTO to the service? Then, my service will be coupled with my DTO's.

Do I define a particular interface for each service method? If so, these are effectively their own DTO's, and I might as well define a DTO per service input permutation.

Assuming my service takes in DTO,

1. In service method, do business logic and make calls to repositories
2. In repositories, CRUD stuff
3. Return final result from service method to API
4. Cast to DTO and return from API to Internet

Now, should my repositories strictly deal in Domain objects? If so, who is responsible for the casting? (The service?)

Finally, with validation in mind, I am thinking:

- Validate up-front using one of the following: `ModelStateActionFilter` (before action execution), during casting to whatever the service needs to take as input. So, this would be ensuring that the `CreateUserService` was receiving an object with a `Username` and `Password`.
- Validate in service method using repositories and other services that username is unique and password is strong enough
- Validate at DAL level to ensure Entity Framework is happy

My question is, which (if any) objects should I be putting `System.DataAnnotations` on? Is there any type of model in this stack that should be responsible in any part for its own validation?

Thanks for any philosophical help.

Comment: This question should be on programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

This question ...

Since your question is long I may miss addressing some points, but here we go. By the way, this is all "in my opinion", you should change things as you see fit to better fit your needs.

1. Get rid of the word "N-Tier". The cool kids these days are using "Onion Architecture".
2. Start with a "Core" project. This is where all your core objects will sit. You will have a Customer, An Order, A Product, etc. At this level, do not worry about about the database, Web API, or UI. Your objects should have methods, properties, and behaviors. Everything should NOT be `Public { get; set; }` here. Oh ya, don't use Interfaces if you don't explicitly need them here.
3. After your "Core" project, you can worry about how to store this objects. You can create a "Repository / DAL" project. Your Repositories should take in your Aggregate root. It is it's job to figure out how to put that in the database.
4. Now "Service" project. Service is easy. Your services are responsible for: Getting Object from Repository, Calling method on Object, Putting Object back in Repository. Now, your services can either return or accept the "Core" objects, or expose their own DTOs.
5. Your WEB API / MVC Project will have your interaction with the user. It will call Service to get anything it wants. Here you can use View Models to present to the user instead of the Core objects.

-- ok that't it --

But here are some explicit answers to your questions:

1. Web Api should never call repository directly.
2. Mapping from whatever your service returns into the Web Api DTO/View Model should happen in the Web Api project.
3. Validation: Web Api can validate everything in order to help the user. Additionally, Core should validate well, core stuff, etc ... validation will end up in a lot of places.
4. Do not define interfaces for each service. If there is only one implementation, it prob should not be an interface.
5. In Service method, you do NOT do business logic. Logic goes inside the core objects.
6. Yes, repositories strictly with Core / Domain objects. And yes, Services job to give it to em.
7. System.DataAnnotations goes in Web Api "View / Models / DTOs"

Comment: Business logic goes in core objects ? what if the data returned to the user is a composite of different objects and they need to be validated together. and also business rules will affect the UI itself. so is there's a better place to implement my business rules ?

Comment: @IKashef If the business rule specifies how the UI should behave, it should not be a business rule at all. The UI should be a representation of the current state of the business. HTML, Buttons, IOS Apps, Animations, ... those are all ways to represent the state of the business.

Comment: but these rules are related to business in logic. for example if the product status is pending then can be edited or deleted. if status if sold it must be read only. these are business rules right ? and it's not convenient to enforce these rules on the server side only. the application should not display a button that is disabled for example (the edit button) it should be hidden in the first place. If you know what am talking about but still think they are not business rules can you please explain a good architecture that's close to the one you suggested in your answer ?

Comment: @IKashef Obviously this conversation can get out of control very quickly but ...Lets say your business rule is "If the product status is pending, then it can be edited or deleted." In that case your product object might have properties called `CanDelete` and `CanEdit`. Internally when you read those, they will only return `true` if status is `pending`. So the UI hides or shows the button based only on those properties, not the business rule itself.

Comment: I totally agree. just wanted an answer with reference to the architecture you suggested here. Thank you for the hint and if I have more questions I will just post a new one. Thank you